# SWI-Prolog: ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I'm trying to create a program that prints how many smooth numbers are within an interval. A part of the code is here:

```
countsmooth(_, [], _, _, Count) :-
   Count is 0.
countsmooth(X, [H|T], Min, Max, Count) :-
   (  Y is X*H,
      Y =< Max 
   -> (  Y >= Min 
      -> NewX is X*H,
         countsmooth(X, T, Min, Max, NCount1),
         countsmooth(NewX, [H|T], Min, Max, NCount2),
         Count is (1+NCount1+NCount2)

      ;  NewX is X*H,
         countsmooth(X, T, Min, Max, NCount1),
         countsmooth(NewX, [H|T], Min, Max, NCount2),
         Count is (NCount1+NCount2)
      )
   ;  Count is 0
   ).

smooth(B, I, J, Smooths) :- 
   (  B =< 1 
   -> Smooths is 0
   ;  I =:= 1 
   -> primes(B, FilPrimes),
      countsmooth(1, Filprimes, I, J, Count),
      Smooths is (1+Count)
   ;  primes(B, FilPrimes),
      countsmooth(1, Filprimes, I, J, Count),
      Smooths is Count
   ).
```

There is also a predicate `primes` that creates all prime numbers from `2` to `B`.

For example, if `B = 11`, then `FilPrimes = [2,3,5,7,11]`.

When I call `countsmooth` in SWI-Prolog like
`?- countsmooth(1, [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23], 1, 100000000, Count)`.
I get a result.

But when I call `smooth` like `?- smooth(2,100,10000,Smooths).`
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry. I have been trying all day to find out what was going wrong and finally I saw that in same places I had written "FilPrimes" and in some other places "Filprimes".

I'm such an idiot!

Comment: In general, you can trace the execution with SWI-Prolog's graphical tracer. To see what happens when Goal is called, try ?- gtrace, Goal.